# Microsoft Owin Response Body Encoding

Tags: c#, owin, owin-middleware

In my `OwinMiddleware` I just write out to the body:

```
await context.Response.Body.WriteStringAsync("Hey There");
```

The raw response I get in Fiddler is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Fri, 13 May 2016 16:00:07 GMT

A
/hey/there
5
there
9
Hey There
26
{ec86d5c7-4ea4-437f-be2a-4e294b655227}
0
```

And Fiddler is saying this encoded (with a message saying please click here decode)

The single letters and numbers are not mine. I wrote `/hey/there` and `there` and `Hey There` and the `Guid` with braces.

How do I just get the plain text response?

Comment: It looks like you are getting a plain-text response. It's just using chunked encoding. Each individual string you're sending is getting sent to the client immediately (with a leading length indicator, per the rules of chunked encoding).

Comment: Yeah okay, so I shall just change the way I write to the stream then

Comment: @CallumLinington why? The client should be able to handle the response even if it's chunked.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yeah that is also a very good point

Comment: No problem here. Move along.